# Bugs in API 2.2 "/search/advanced" with a "q" parameter

Tags: support, bug, api-v2.2, search

How can we handle these problems?

- Result for `sort=relevance&order=desc` is similar to
  `sort=relevance&order=desc`.
- Very poor caching system: After some queries, you may receive the same
  results for `sort=relevance` and `sort=votes`.
- Its result is different from `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=`'s.

Answer (score 1):

There's indeed no difference between `order=asc` and `order=desc`; perhaps this is a limitation of [Elasticsearch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/295232) which powers the Stack Exchange search engine (both the API and on the sites). To be fair, to find the most irrelevant search result on the site you have to go to the last page yourself. The API is no different.

There is some difference between the API and the site, but have you seen this note on the documentation page (emphasis mine):

> Searches a site for any *questions* which fit the given criteria.

Otherwise, the top results when searching for test with the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=relevance&q=test&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) and [on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=test&searchOn=1) seem to match.

But if you want to mimic site search with the API, you're better off using the [`/search/excerpts`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) method.